# FoldList or NestWhileList applied to Insert function

Tags: list-manipulation, insert

I have 3 list namely, `start = {{Sqrt[5], 3}, {Sqrt[13], 1}}; toAdd = {{7, 2}, {7, 5}, {1, 1}}; idx = {2, 3, 4};`. I can write a `While` loop

```
i = 1;
While[i <=  Length[toAdd], 

start = Insert[start, toAdd[[i]], idx[[i]]]; 

i++
]
```

So I get `start = {{Sqrt[5], 3}, {7, 2}, {7, 5}, {1, 1}, {Sqrt[13], 1}}`.

I there a way I can use `FoldList` or `NestWhileList` with `Insert` to achieve the same results since at each step in the `While` loop I am updating `start`.

Comment: Are you always bookending list {b,c,d} with {a, e}, to produce {a,b,c,d,e}?  Or are you envisaging more complicated structures such as {b,c,d} with idx = {2,3,5} which would presumably produce {a,b,c,e,d} ... ??

Comment: More complicated structures as you have illustrated in your example. Sorry for not mentioning that.

Answer (score 5):

```
Fold[Insert[#1, #2[[1]], #2[[2]]] &, start, Transpose[{toAdd, idx}]]
(*{{Sqrt[5], 3}, {7, 2}, {7, 5}, {1, 1}, {Sqrt[13], 1}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

A different approach:  The OP has 2 lists, say: `{x, y, z}`  and `{a,b}`

He wants to create a combined list, where elements `{x,y,z}` get slotted into prescribed index positions, say slots:

```
 ind = {2,3,5}
```

with complement slots:

```
 comp = Complement[Range[5],ind]
```

> {1,4}

The other list `{a,b}` then gets slotted, in order, into the remaining spots. This can be done directly, without requiring iteration or Folding, as per:

```
lis = Table[0, 5];
lis[[ind]] = {x, y, z};
lis[[comp]] = {a, b};
lis
```

> {a, x, y, b, z}

Another approach is to use `SparseArray` which has a convenient syntax:

```
SparseArray[{ind->{x,y,z}, comp->{a,b}}]//Normal
```

> {a, x, y, b, z}

The only downside to the latter is that in order to use `SparseArray`, the elements `a, b, x, y, z` cannot themselves be lists.